# How to use an operator $exists inside an $elemMatch using MongoEngine syntax

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, odm

Is it possible to use an $exists operator inside an $elemMatch using MongoEngine?

I would like to do something like:

```
Location.objects(accessPoints__match={'deletedAt__exists': True, 'mac': "AC-86-74-xx-xx-xx"})
```

I think MongoEngine assumes that deletedAt__exists is the name of attribute in my document.

But the only way I found out to work is combining syntaxes:

```
Location.objects(accessPoints__match={'deletedAt': {'$exists': True}, 'mac': "AC-86-74-02-6E-70"})
```

Combining MongoEngine syntax and pure MongoDB syntax.